# send response HTTP 200 SUCCESS in php

Tags: php, html

I need to send an HTTP 200 response to the string 'SUCCESS', but my php server version is 5.2.17!

In my case, the webhook sends data to the capture to a file called notification.php, I read the contentes, save in the database and need to send a response but do not know how to do this!

Does anyone know how to do this in php 5.2.17?

I tried the following ways without success:

```
// error 1
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo "SUCCESS";

// error 2
$httpStatusCode = 200;
$httpStatusMsg  = 'SUCCESS';
$protocol = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.0';
header($protocol.' '.$httpStatusCode.' '.$httpStatusMsg);

// error 3
header("200 SUCCESS");
return "200 SUCCESS";

// error 4
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo 'SUCCESS';

// error 5
header('Content-Type: application/json');
return 'SUCCESS';

//error 6
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('SUCCESS');

///error 7
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$success =json_encode('SUCCESS');
header($success);


///error 8
header("HTTP/1.1 200 SUCCESS");
header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8");

///error 9
header("HTTP/1.1 200");
header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8");
result 'SUCCESS';

//error 10
header("Content-Type:application/json;");
header('HTTP/1.0 200 SUCCESS');

// error 11
$code = 200;
$text = 'OK';
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.0');
header($protocol . ' ' . $code . ' ' . $text);
$GLOBALS['http_response_code'] = $code;
echo 'SUCCESS';
```

My PhpCode

```
<?php
 $src_data = $_REQUEST["data"];           
 $une_data = stripslashes($src_data);
 $data = json_decode($une_data);

 //get payment data
 $id_cob  = $data->payment->id;
 $id_cus  = $data->payment->customer;
 $status  = $data->payment->status;
 $dtsts   = date("Y-m-d");

 if ($data->event == 'PAYMENT_RECEIVED') {
// post client
include('dbconnection.php');
$qryn  = "UPDATE PAYMENTS SET STATUS='$status', DATASTATUS='$dtsts' WHERE ID_COB_ASAAS='$id_cob' AND ID_CLI_ASAAS='$id_cus'";
    mysql_query($qryn,$cnx);
 } 

// webhook return
// my solution was:
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
echo 'SUCCESS';
return;

?>
```

Comment: The header function hasn't been changed for a loooong time. Regardless there is really NO EXCUSE to run software that hasn't received security updates for 6 years.

Comment: PHP 5.2 was discontinued in 2011. It's highly dangerous and insecure to run. Time to upgrade.

Comment: ceejayoz: Unfortunately it is a shared hosting. As a client, depending on the hosting server.

Comment: @prmas Then it's time to get a new host, because yours is dangerous and incompetent.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try:

```
$code = 200;
$text = 'OK';
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.0');
header($protocol . ' ' . $code . ' ' . $text);
$GLOBALS['http_response_code'] = $code;
echo 'SUCCESS';
```

Comment: This is a pretty overcomplicated approach.

Comment: Do you mean because of the use of variables?

Comment: Thanks Shadi, but without success!

Comment: Pedro, would you justify your comment?

Comment: Shadi Shaaban, thanks. My solution was header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
echo 'SUCCESS'; return;

Comment: Excellent, glad you could get it to work, so I realize here that you were writing SUCCESS instead of OK?

Answer (score 5):

200 is the standard return code.

So

```
<?php
echo 'SUCCESS';
```

should basically be enough.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I did not succeed. I include php code I'm using, might help.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
echo "SUCCESS";
http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater
```

Which seems to be working.